# Android emulator 33 expresso test not working onView perform swipe

Tags: android, testing, android-emulator

I am testing an emulator with the last version, 33, but i am not able to get the emulator to drag the screen in any direction, it is not working the onView(x).perform(swipeUp()) or down or left or whatever, and i cant find anything on internet, i dont know what is the problem

Comment: Are you sure there isn’t any overlay or dialogs on the screen consuming the touch events?

Comment: dont think so, does not work in any screen and if i use a 32 api emulator it works